# How to merge/append/add two models for threading in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, c++14

I am kinda newbie so if this post is in wrong place just inform me please.

I am trying to use threads for "for loops" in my program but according to my research `model->setData` is not compatible with threading.

So my solutions is :
I am gonna use different models in each thread and at the and I am gonna merge them into one to show in tableview.

But I am not familiar with Qt so I kinda stuck here I dont know how to merge two models each other, could you please check my code ?

```
{
    t2 = std::thread{[&]{
        const auto row_size = (RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file.size()
        const auto col_size = RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file[0].size();
        for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < (row_size+1) / 2)  ; i++)
        {
            for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j < col_size;j++)
            {
                std::string temp = RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file[i][j];
                QModelIndex index = model ->index(i,j,QModelIndex());
                model->setData(index,temp.c_str());
            }
        }
    }};

    //t3 = std::thread{[&]{
    //    const auto row_size = (RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file.size()
    //    const auto col_size = RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file[0].size();
    //    for(unsigned int i = (row_size+1) / 2) ; i < row_size;i++)
    //    {
    //        for(unsigned int j = 0 ; j < col_size;j++)
    //        {
    //            std::string temp = RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file[i][j];
    //            QModelIndex index = model ->index(i,j,QModelIndex());
    //            model->setData(index,temp.c_str());
    //        }
    //    }
    //}};

    t2.join();
    //t3.join();

    const auto tvr = ui->tableView_results;
    tvr->setModel(model);
    tvr->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
    tvr->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
}
```

Thank you for your help ...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please checkout https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question.  I think we have an XY problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem here.  Why do you want to use threads?

Comment: My question is "what actually is your question?"  The code looks OK so far (you split the work between two threads.  Now you need to merge the models.  What are you having trouble with?  Are you sure multi-threading the loop is worth the expense of merging models?

Comment: first of all thanks for commenting. My problem is I cannot use mutex to models because it is not thread safe it slows a lot, so my solutions is merge models How can I do that ?

Comment: Models are actually facades for model data, a convenient front-end for the model's data. Instead of merging *models*, you need a way to merge the *data* for the model itself. This is your XY Problem. =)

Comment: Well, that's half of your XY Problem. The other half Michael mentioned above: do you really need to thread these operations?

Comment: yes I have to use threads :/

Comment: Your model is I assume a QObject. These are compatible to multithreading. Simply search QObject, multithreading     in a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
vector<std::string> answers;
std::mutex mx_answers;

auto rows = RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file.size();
auto cols = RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file[0].size();
answers.reserve(rows *cols);
auto answers_fill_it = answers.begin();

vector<std::thread> ts;
ts.reserve(rows);
auto rows = RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file.size();
for (row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
{
    ts.emplace_back([&](
        vector<std::string> local_answers;
        local_answers.reserve(cols);
        for (unsigned col = 0; col < cols; ++col) {
            local_answers.push_back(RegexOperations_.indexed_arranged_file[row][col]);
        };
        lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx_answers);
        std::copy(local_answers.begin(), local_answers.end(), answers_fill_it);));
}
auto answer_it = answers.begin();

for (auto t & : ts)
    if (t.joinable())
        t.join();

for (auto row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    for (auto col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
    {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(row, col, QModelIndex());
        model->setData(index, *answer_it;
        ++answer_it;
    }
```

It splits it up to a thread per row and as each thread is done it adds that row's results to a global vector of strings.

When all threads are done the model is updated.

Comment: Edited to remove bug (answer_it incremented twice)